# dynamic linking without libc

Tags: c, linux, llvm

I'm creating a programming language with LLVM and I want dynamic linking. I first tried with vulkan. optimized LLVM IR from my compiler:

```
; ModuleID = 'test1.sc'
source_filename = "test1.sc"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"

%vk_instance_create_info = type { i32, ptr, i32, ptr, i32, ptr, i32, ptr }

declare i32 @vkCreateInstance(ptr, ptr, ptr) local_unnamed_addr

; Function Attrs: noreturn
define void @_start() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %vki = alloca ptr, align 8
  %ci = alloca %vk_instance_create_info, align 8
  store i32 1, ptr %ci, align 8
  %.fca.1.gep = getelementptr inbounds %vk_instance_create_info, ptr %ci, i64 0, i32 1
  store ptr null, ptr %.fca.1.gep, align 8
  %.fca.2.gep = getelementptr inbounds %vk_instance_create_info, ptr %ci, i64 0, i32 2
  store i32 0, ptr %.fca.2.gep, align 8
  %.fca.3.gep = getelementptr inbounds %vk_instance_create_info, ptr %ci, i64 0, i32 3
  store ptr null, ptr %.fca.3.gep, align 8
  %.fca.4.gep = getelementptr inbounds %vk_instance_create_info, ptr %ci, i64 0, i32 4
  store i32 0, ptr %.fca.4.gep, align 8
  %.fca.6.gep = getelementptr inbounds %vk_instance_create_info, ptr %ci, i64 0, i32 6
  store i32 0, ptr %.fca.6.gep, align 8
  %1 = call i32 @vkCreateInstance(ptr nonnull %ci, ptr null, ptr nonnull %vki)
  %2 = call i64 asm sideeffect inteldialect "syscall", "={rax},{rax},{rdi},~{rcx},~{r11}"(i64 60, i64 0) #1
  unreachable
}

attributes #0 = { noreturn }
attributes #1 = { nounwind }
```

Then I ran `ld.lld /lib64/libvulkan.so.1 out.o --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. `./a.out` -> `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Then I tried with wayland-client:

```
; ModuleID = 'test1.sc'
source_filename = "test1.sc"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"

declare ptr @wl_display_connect(i64) local_unnamed_addr

; Function Attrs: noreturn
define void @_start() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %1 = tail call ptr @wl_display_connect(i64 0)
  %2 = tail call i64 asm sideeffect inteldialect "syscall", "={rax},{rax},{rdi},~{rcx},~{r11}"(i64 60, i64 0) #1
  unreachable
}

attributes #0 = { noreturn }
attributes #1 = { nounwind }
```

That worked!? Then I tried with C:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main(void) {
    VkInstance inst;
    vkCreateInstance(&(VkInstanceCreateInfo) {VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO}, 0, &inst);
}
```

`gcc vktest.c /lib64/libvulkan.so.1 -o vktest` (for some reason it doesn't recognize -lvulkan) - it works. `gcc vktest.c /lib64/libvulkan.so.1 -o vktest -nostartfiles`, replace main with _start and add `for (;;) ;` - doesn't work. I also tried with wayland-client and it always worked:

```
#include <wayland-client.h>

void _start(void) {
    wl_display_connect(0);
    for (;;) ;
}
```

|  | C with libc | C without libc | my language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vulkan | works | doesn't work | doesn't work |
| wayland-client | works | works | works |

I saw that the relocation types are different (using `readelf -a`).

What is going on? What magic is libc doing and how to do it without libc?

Comment: libc is where the dynamic linker is! unfortunately. I bet libvulkan is calling dlopen. Do you have dlopen? (and if not, why does the program successfully load...?)